# Bash Script Rename and Assign Number to File

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to make a bash script based on some I've found but I can't make any of those works!

I need to do is very simple!

Foreach file in the directory, rename all with a string (fixed)+number (min.1 - max (number of files))!

I just can't make it works!

If anyone could help me..

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a") mv -- "$i" "$new" let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: post your script so far

Comment: As well as showing us what you've tried and explaining where you're stuck, You need to show us an example of what you mean as it's currently not clear.

Comment: I'm trying but this doesn't works!

Comment: answer below based on making the code work. not too clear what you mean here : `string (fixed)+number (min.1 - max (number of files))`. interpretation below is just to rename to a zeropadded numeric like 0001.jpg etc. ( as suggested by your code )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rename_images.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1;
for i in *.jpg; 
do  
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a");
  mv "$i" "$new";
  let a=a+1;
done
```

**output**

```
$ touch one.jpg two.jpg;
$ ls
one.jpg  rename_images.sh  two.jpg
$ ./rename_images.sh 
$ ls
0001.jpg  0002.jpg  rename_images.sh
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I notice one thing! What's the order of the sutff? For example im trying to do this for a list of files (Episodes like "S01E01")

Comment: the files are looped in dictionary sort order